# SEO Urls with htaccess and SSL

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have an issue where the following rule works without SSL however when i change to https the rule doesn't work at all

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signins/?$ /login.php
```

Its driving me crazy please help :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you put more details, what doesn't work?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: mod_rewrite questions are not off-topic for SO.

Comment: @anubhava that's not my interpretation of http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RowlandShaw: There are about 13000 questions here using `mod_rewrite` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite and more than 23000 using `.htaccess` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess

Comment: @anubhava about 4% of the questions on webmasters are tagged in that manner; does that make it more on-topic here or there? Possibly neither, but as I already said, my interpretation of what is considered on-topic per the help pages doesn't include configuration of web servers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `<VirtualHost>` config for your `https site` it might be using a different `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.